# Import Error : ImportError: cannot import name 'abc' from 'bson.py3compat'

Tags: python

How can i solve this error. It will generate while running program.

```
from bson import ObjectId
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

Comment: Please add exact error message, including the line where it was thrown; if possible, add the entire traceback.

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'abc' from 'bson.py3compat'         It will show error in def default(self,o):

Answer (score 74, accepted):

That's most likely due to version mismatches.

This worked for me:

```
pip uninstall bson
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo
```

Comment: wont you install bson again?

Comment: From the pymongo pypi page: Do not install the “bson” package from pypi. PyMongo comes with its own bson package; doing “easy_install bson” installs a third-party package that is incompatible with PyMongo.