# Dockerize Flask: Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to dockerize my Flask API. As soon as I try to start my image I receive the message:

```
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'python -m flask run --help' for help.

Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.
```

If I am starting the Flask App with my terminal `python -m flask run`  everything works like intended.
And right now I am stuck on this problem.

Here is my Code:

```
from flask import Flask
from bson import json_util
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_cors import CORS
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://194.163.147.192:27017/test"
CORS(app)
mongo = PyMongo(app)


def parse_json(data):
    return json.loads(json_util.dumps(data))


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello'


@app.route('/residential', methods=['GET'])
def find_residential():  # put application's code here
    test = mongo.db.acs.find_one({"name": "Residential"})
    response = Flask.jsonify(parse_json(test))
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response


@app.route('/commercial', methods=['GET'])
def find_commercial():  # put application's code here
    test = mongo.db.acs.find_one({"name": "Commercial"})
    response = Flask.jsonify(parse_json(test))
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response


@app.route('/healthcare', methods=['GET'])
def find_health_care():  # put application's code here
    test = mongo.db.acs.find_one({"name": "Health Care"})
    response = Flask.jsonify(parse_json(test))
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response


@app.route('/germany', methods=['GET'])
def find_germany():
    test = mongo.db.germanies.find_one()
    response = Flask.jsonify(parse_json(test))
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = False
    app.run()
```

My requirements.txt looks like this

```
bson==0.5.10
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
pymongo==3.12.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.0.2
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /api
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I am thankful for any help :)

Project structure is like:

```
API
L venv
L app.py
L Dockerfile
L requirements.txt
```

Comment: What is the structure of your project directory? It's unclear where you 'code' file is, what it's called or whether there is anything else that might be interfering in this process. I can't really reproduce this faithfully without more details.

Comment: edit: add folder structure

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is, I think, with your requirements file. In that you include `bson` as a dependency, which is also included in the `pymongo` library. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149801/import-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-abc-from-bson-py3compat). Removing it seems to solve the issue:

```
 ~/tmp/so_q $ docker build -t myimage .                                                             8s nathanielford@nford 20:51:04
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB

...

Successfully tagged myimage:latest
 ~/tmp/so_q $ docker run myimage                                                                   13s nathanielford@nford 20:51:26
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.9.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help... but I had the same issue too and I've just fixed it changing my `entrypoint.sh` file.

Before I was starting the flask app using:

```
flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

And now I'm using gunicorn:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app
```

So I had to add `gunicorn` in the `requirements.txt` file too.